# Synchronous replication between two NAS Business Storage and Ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nas, replication

My setup is I have two NAS setup. I can mount those NAS in a Linux Server (Ubuntu or Centos) and plan on writing on both NAS synchronously or replicate frmo one nas to the other one real-time.

Anyone have any ideas how can i do this? I've been looking at glusterfs but is there any other option i can use?

Thanks alot for the help.